# Vivaldi flickering while watching videos

Tags: display, web-browser

Vivaldi browser causes screen flickering while playing videos, which is very annoying. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't found one. This appears to be an ongoing issue in many browsers on elementary. I've seen reports of it occurring in Firefox, Chrome, and Epiphany. Looks like now Vivaldi.

Comment: I've been using Chrome and Firefox for a long time on elementary and I had no problems with them. It only happens with Vivaldi.

Answer (score 1):

Open Vivaldi with –disable-gpu will also solve.Open terminal and in your terminal type the below code and hit the enter key.

`vivaldi --diable-gpu`
or try

`vivaldi --disable-gpu-vsync`

From: [connect.com](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-vivaldi-flickering-screen-in-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux/4925/)